# Quadratic reciprocity and gamma function

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

Is there a direct connection between gamma function and quadratic reciprocity ?
I am currently writing about quadratic reciprocity and I am interested in including gamma function as suggested by a professor previously however, when I searched about gamma function I could not find something that helps in quadratic reciprocity or any very close connection.
Any idea would be appreciated  ?